# TimeCircles - issues when hiding time units

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm using [TimeCircles](http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html) and I'm having the following issues - when I have all 4 time units it's all working fine:

[image]

But then if I decide to remove the first one (change the settings to:

```
"Days": {
      "text": "Days",
      "color": "#FFCC66",
      "show": false
 }
```

Then the 'hours' unit is affected as well:

[image]

It's now being shown as 0 and starts moving at the same speed as the 'seconds' circle. It's the same if I hide the hours field , then the minutes one is affected.

[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue? I'd appreciate some help, thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you create snippet?

Comment: @Satpal well I'm basically using the default configuration that is on the website I linked to - I haven't made any changes.

Comment: Why don't you copy their code after unchecking the days at their site? I think you may have removed the comma or something

Comment: @mplungjan yeah copying the code again fixed it, I think for some reason choosing a custom id for the element seemed to have been causing the issue ... anyways thanks for the suggestion!